# Select Parent and Children With MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this question comes up often, but today I can't find the answer I'm looking for. I have a table with this schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `id` bigint(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `parent_id` bigint(10) unsigned default 0,
    `date_sent` datetime not null,
    `content` text not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'd like to select parent rows, and the children of those rows. I don't allow children to have children, so it's just one parent, with any number of children.

I think I've seen this done with unions before, or inner joins.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Parents are records with no `parent_id`.
Children have `parent_id` equal to the parent comment's `id`.

```
  SELECT ...
    FROM comments AS parent
         LEFT JOIN comments AS child 
         ON child.parent_id = parent.id
   WHERE parent.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY parent.id, child.id;
```

Note that the self-join should be an outer join so that you don't miss parent comments with no children.

Comment: Thanks, a1ex07. I think you meant parent comments w/ no children ;-) I think you should also add to your `WHERE` clause: `p.parent_id IS NULL`. Cheers.

Comment: What if I have childs to childs? wouldn't I need to have multiple joins?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for

```
SELECT p.id, child.*
FROM comments p
INNER JOIN comments child ON (child.parent_id = p.id)
WHERE ....
```

**UPDATE**
 Or `LEFT JOIN` if you want to see rows with no parents

Comment: What if I have childs to childs? wouldn't I need to have multiple joins?

Comment: I want to limit the lookup for parent. how I can put limit on it.

Comment: When I try something like this, mysql throw the error: unknown column in ON clause. Referencing p.id column. My table are different, but the logic is the same, I can't use external column (from FROM clause) in JOIN clause without this error. Help Me!

Answer (score 2):

I've not saying exactly, i think your getting this kind of problem as following as:

Ordered_Item

```
ID | Item_Name
1  | Pizza
2  | Stromboli
```

Ordered_Options

```
Ordered_Item_ID | Option_Number | Value
        1               43         Pepperoni
        1               44         Extra Cheese
        2               44         Extra Cheese
```

Output

```
ID | Item_Name | Option_1 | Option_2
1    Pizza       Pepperoni  Extra Cheese
2    Stromboli     NULL     Extra Cheese
```

And the my suggestions to use this method resolve this problem as there following as:

1. The easiest way would be to make use of the GROUP_CONCAT group
   function here..

> ```
> select 
>         ordered_item.id as `Id`, 
>         ordered_item.Item_Name as `ItemName`,
>
>   GROUP_CONCAT(Ordered_Options.Value) as `Options`
>
>   from ordered_item, ordered_options
>
>   where ordered_item.id=ordered_options.ordered_item_id
>
>   group by ordered_item.id
> ```

Which would output:

```
Id              ItemName       Options
1               Pizza          Pepperoni,Extra Cheese
2               Stromboli      Extra Cheese
```

That way you can have as many options as you want without having to modify your query.

Ah, if you see your results getting cropped, you can increase the size limit of GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 8192;
```