# Create multiple categories with parent, child and grandchild

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create multiple categories with parent, child and grandchild.
And can order by `ordering` field.

```
id  | parent_id |   name    |  ordering
--------------------------------------
1   |     0     |   Men     |   1
2   |     0     |   Women   |   2
3   |     1     |   Shoes   |   3
4   |     2     |   Watches |   4
5   |     1     |   Pants   |   5
6   |     3     |   Sport   |   6
7   |     3     |   Casual  |   7
8   |     2     |   Book    |   8
```

I want this result

```
Men
  Shoes
     Sport
     Casual
  Pants
Women
  Watches
  Book
```

Array out put

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parent_id] => 0
        [name] => Men
        [ordering] => 1
        [level] => parent    //NEEDED
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [parent_id] => 0
        [name] => Women
        [ordering] => 2
        [level] => parent    //NEEDED
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => Shoes
        [ordering] => 3
        [level] => child    //NEEDED
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [parent_id] => 2
        [name] => Watches
        [ordering] => 4
        [level] => child    //NEEDED
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => Pants
        [ordering] => 5
        [level] => child    //NEEDED
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [parent_id] => 3
        [name] => Sport
        [ordering] => 6
        [level] => grandchild    //NEEDED
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [parent_id] => 3
        [name] => Casual
        [ordering] => 7
        [level] => grandchild    //NEEDED
    )
[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [parent_id] => 2
        [name] => Book
        [ordering] => 8
        [level] => child    //NEEDED
    )
)
```

Comment: No shoes for women won't end well.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: @AlexK. i used mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found good answer

ref : [Parent child mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171755/parent-child-mysql)

```
select t0.*,
  concat(
      case coalesce(t4.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t4.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t3.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t3.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t2.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t2.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t1.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t1.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t0.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t0.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      cast(t0.id as char)
    ) as path
from mytable t0
    left join mytable t1 on t0.parent_id = t1.Id
    left join mytable t2 on t1.parent_id = t2.Id
    left join mytable t3 on t2.parent_id = t3.Id
    left join mytable t4 on t3.parent_id = t4.Id
order by 
  concat(
      case coalesce(t4.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t4.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t3.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t3.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t2.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t2.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t1.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t1.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      case coalesce(t0.parent_id, 0) 
        when 0 then ''
        else concat(cast(t0.parent_id as char), '\\')
      end,
      cast(t0.id as char)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution to get your level information:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN parent_id = 0 THEN 'Parent'
       ELSE CASE WHEN (SELECT T2.parent_id 
                        FROM tab T2
                        WHERE T2.id = T.parent_id) = 0 THEN 'Child'
                  ELSE 'Grandchild' 
             END
   END AS level
FROM tab T
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea625/7)

To put the content of this SQL into an array you need a server side language like PHP, since you're not using mongoDB or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called "items", you could do the following recursive query to generate names containing the parent and the ordering attribute, then order by the generated name and add spaces before the name according to the level:

```
;WITH itemsHierarchy (id, parent_id, name, generatedname, level)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        i.id, 
        i.parent_id, 
        i.name, 
        CAST(i.name AS varchar(MAX)) as generatedname, 
        1 as level
    FROM items i
    WHERE i.parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        i.id, 
        i.parent_id, 
        i.name,
         CAST(ih.generatedname + '_' + CAST(i.ordering as varchar(2))+ '_' + i.name AS varchar(MAX)), 
         ih.level + 1
    FROM items i
    INNER JOIN itemsHierarchy ih ON i.parent_id = ih.id
)

SELECT REPLICATE('   ', level) + name
FROM itemsHierarchy
ORDER BY generatedname
```

Result:

```
   Men
      Shoes
         Sport
         Casual
      Pants
   Women
      Watches
      Book
```